# jQuery: Fire event only if the windows is being resized

Tags: jquery

I want to change a property if the windows is being resized. How can I go back to the original property after the resize?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div').css('do 1');
});

$(window).resize(function(){
    $('div').css('do 2 and when resize is finished go back to 1');
});
```

Comment: `resize` is an event, you could only do something when it fired, you could not use it as a if condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try modifying your resize function to something like this

http://jsfiddle.net/Varinder/U3MKP/

Below is the code(just in case fiddle link doesnt work)

```
$(document).ready(function() { $('div').css('do 1'); });

var t;
$(window).resize(function() {
   clearTimeout(t);
   $('div').css('do 2');
   t = setTimeout(function() {
     //resize end (sort-of-hacky) event fires here.
     $('div').css('do 1');
   }, 100);
});
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. I had tried with something similar but got tangled in the timeout. Thanks Varinder!

Answer (score 4):

`.resize()` is an event, not a boolean property.

So you can assign a handler that fires when the window is being resized.

**i.e.**

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    $('body').prepend('<div>' + $(window).width() + '</div>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to do something like:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  var n = $(window).width;
  var trigger_num = 1000;

  if (n > trigger_num) {
    $('div').css('do something');
  } 
  else {
    $('div').css('do something else');
  }
});
```

The trigger number is basically a number that you define to trigger the CSS when the window exceeds a certain size. This of course can be modified with <, ==, etc.

Comment: It's a fluid design, I want this event to happen every time someone resizes, no matter from or to which size

Comment: All you need is what @Marko provided then. $(window).resize(function() { *code* });

Answer (score -1):

```
$(window).on( "resize" , function(){
 // do something
});
```

I recommend throttling this function because it will be fired every time a pixel size is changed. So use something like underscorejs use this. This will fire the code only every 60 frames per second.

```
$(window).on( "resize" , _.throttle( function(){ 
    // do something 
} , 1000/60 ) );
```

Comment: You are not answering the question asked. :)